# Save a mysql tabular data in redis

Tags: php, redis

I am new in redis, so may be my question is wrong.

I want to save users data in redis.

for example let data is -

```
    first_name            last_name                  email
    abc                   xyz                        abc@example.com
    def                   hig                        def@example.com
```

My code is -

let we are getting data in post array

```
        require "predis/autoload.php";
        Predis\Autoloader::register();

        $redis = new Predis\Client(array(
         "scheme" => "tcp",
         "host" => "127.0.0.1",
         "port" => 6379));

        $redis->incr("id");
        $user_id = $redis->get("id");


        $redis->hset("users", 'id', $user_id);
        foreach($_POST as $key  =>  $post_values){
            $redis->hset("users", $key, $post_values);

        }
```

when I see users data using command

```
$users = $redis->hgetall("users");
```

second user is overlapping first one.
I think the id is not correctly mapping users data.

Please suggest.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better using hmset and hmget rather than just the singular hset, since hmset can use multiple fields linked to one overarching key

Comment: Make a hash key using unique key in your table (Ex. email in your case). store the data in redis corresponding to it.

Comment: Thanks , I am trying.

Comment: @JammyDodger231 I am trying hmset and its good way to save  data which is in array, but there is any way so that I can update any field directly. For example I want to update email then how can I do ?

Comment: @Rich5757 I have put an answer down now, I think that would be the best way of going about it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using hmset rather than just hset so using hmset, the easiest way I think would be using the name of the array being the user ID:

```
HMSET user1 email "test@email.com" username "MyUser"
```

Then you could use

```
HMGET user1 email
```

To get the email for user 1

For PHP I use https://github.com/henderjon/redis below is how you would use this to set these same commands in PHP

```
$redis = (new \Redis\RedisProtocol())->connect('127.0.0.1', '6379');
$redis->hmset("user1", ["email", "test@email.com", "username", "MyUser"]);
```

Then retrieving would be:

```
($redis->hmget("user1", ['email']))[0]
```

Comment: Thanks , I am testing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is pretty simple you are using "users" to store the data for all the users, whereas each user is itself a hash. So append the ID with the string "users" and you are good to go.

```
$redis->hset("users", 'id', $user_id);
Change it like $redis->hset("users:"+$user_id, 'id', $user_id);
foreach($_POST as $key  =>  $post_values){
        $redis->hset("users:"+$user_id, $key, $post_values);

    }
```

Hope this helps